# How to use the value in ngRepeat as a dynamic way to access a scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have a set of value that I would like to dynamically generate in my view. How can I go about doing it in the following way?

```
$scope.mainKeyMapping = [
    {
        name: 'category1',
        otherThings: ''
    }, 
    {
        name: 'category2',
        otherThings: ''
    }, 
    {
        name: 'category3',
        otherThings: ''
    }, 
    {
        name: 'category4',
        otherThings: ''
    }, 
    {
        name: 'category5',
        otherThings: ''
    }
];


$scope.category1 = {something....}
$scope.category2 = {something....}
$scope.category3 = {something....}
$scope.category4 = {something....}
$scope.category5 = {something....}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in mainKeyMapping">


    {{category1}} // outputs obj

    {{cat.name}} // outputs string "category1" <----- how do I output the obj?


</div>
```

Comment: Could you set it up like: `$scope.obj.category1 = {...}`, `$scope.obj.category2 = {...}`, etc.?

Comment: Alternately, you could set `$scope.obj = $scope`.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard this is quite an ugly recommendation. The alternative you are talking about would be to use `myController as ctrl` and use `ctrl[categoryName]`

Comment: @ChrisBouchard I don't want to group the categories into one object because I want to avoid too many loops which is quite costly atm.

Answer (score 1):

First, put your categories into a collection:

```
$scope.categories = {
 category1: {something....},
 category2: {something....}
};
```

Now simply access the right category in your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in mainKeyMapping">

  {{categories.category1}} // outputs obj

  {{categories[cat.name]}} // outputs obj

</div>
```